# Force CMake to use MSVC with Ninja

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, ninja

I am trying to compile [aseprite](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite) on 64-bit Windows and using CMake and Ninja to compile it

When I am running CMake I see that it is using MINGW64 to make the build files, even though it is mentioned that MinGW is not supported. I tried writing `-DCMAKE_IGNORE_PATH=C:\MinGW\bin` but it seemed to ignore it, and when running `ninja aseprite` I get an error

GENERATION:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DLAF_BACKEND=skia -DSKIA_DIR=C:\deps\skia -DSKIA_LIBRARY_DIR=C:\deps\skia\out\Release-x64 -DCMAKE_IGNORE_PATH=C:\mingw64\bin -G Ninja ..
```

I have checked and all dependencies exist

ERROR:

```
FAILED: bin/modp_b64_gen.exe
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -O2 -g -DNDEBUG   laf/third_party/CMakeFiles/modp_b64_gen.dir/stringencoders/src/arraytoc.c.obj laf/third_party/CMakeFiles/modp_b64_gen.dir/stringencoders/src/modp_b64_gen.c.obj  -o bin\modp_b64_gen.exe -Wl,--out-implib,lib\libmodp_b64_gen.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 wsock32.lib ws2_32.lib && cd ."
gcc.exe: error: wsock32.lib: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: ws2_32.lib: No such file or directory
[563/1514] Building CXX object third_party/harfbuzz/CMakeFiles/harfbuzz.dir/src/hb-ot-layout.cc.obj
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I saw an [issue](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/issues/2063) on github, and the solution was to change from GCC to MSVC, but its not mentioned how to force MSVC for the generation process.
When I delete mingw64 from PATH, it still somehow finds it, if I remove the folder it throws an error that GCC was not found.

How do I force MSVC on CMake?

Comment: I believe `cmake -G Ninja` needs to be `cmake -GNinja` or `cmake -G "Ninja"`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it works anyways, it says that build files were written.  The error occurs when I write `ninja aseprite`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the environment variable `CC` to `cl`

```
set CC=cl
```